# Which JSON-LD version SDTT uses

Tags: json-ld, google-rich-snippets-tool

Google Structured Data Testing Tool (SDTT) invalidates the JSON-LD where as jsonlint and jsonplayground for version 1.1 (https://json-ld.org/playground-dev/) validates below.

```json
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
    "ex": "http://schema.org/",
    "name": {
      "@id": "ex:name",
      "@container": "@language"
    },
    "@version": 1.1
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "@id": "http://www.appointmentwala.com/C1.json#LocalBusiness1",
      "name": {
        "en": "Yastika Eclectic Software",
        "hi": "यस्तिका एक्लेक्टिक सॉफ्टवेयर"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is SDTT using the JSON-LD 1.0 and do not consider the `"@version": 1.1` in the context?